# Windows 10 Photo App cannot modify images in the AppData folder

Tags: c#, appdata

I am making use the the AppData folder by creating images there and shelling out to Windows (with Process.Start( path-to-image )).  This causes the built in photo viewer/editor to start up with the image in question.  When I look at the process created for this, it shows the following as the executable:

```
Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2018.18041.15530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Now, when I edit the photo in the app and try to save it over the existing image file, the photo app says:

```
Opps!  We couldn't save that one.
```

However, if I save a copy right next to it with a different name, all is good.

I've made sure that the permissions allow writing on the file, etc.

Note that if I use the Paint 3D app to edit the image, I can overwrite the original file.

My question is: Is there something I am doing wrong, or is there a better place I should be using for app specific data where I want my user to be able to modify the image with the photo app.

**Update:**

Even when I try to start the "ms-paint:" app (Paint 3D), I can't seen to be able to pass an argument to it.

I am left with starting the "basic" paint app which can't save the image, or starting the paint 3d app which can't take an argument.

Comment: Are you sure about the rights? For the whole folder?

Comment: Show a minimal version of the code, where you are saving the file... oh i thought it was a file handle thing, however it 3D paint can save it, then all bets are off.. anyway id double check you dont have a handle to the image somewhere in your code

Comment: PepitoSH, yes, I verified the permissions for the folder.  Note that Paint 3D can write over the image, while the photo app cannot.

Comment: TheGeneral, the code that writes the file is simply creating a FIleStream with Create, then writing the bytes.  I also tried simply copying the image to the same location with Window's file browser with the same results.

Comment: Does this still happen when your application is closed?

Comment: TheGeneral, yes, even when my app is not running.

Comment: Could you try instead of Process.Start(path-to-image) to launch the application directly and put path-to-image in the command arguments?

Comment: PepitoSH, I originally did that, and Windows spawns the photo app which cannot write the file.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have decided that the AppData directory should only be used for data that the app is going to read and write.  It should **not** be used for the purposes of allowing a user to see/edit files there.

So, I now will place images that are meant to be edited by the user into that user's Pictures directory.  I use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures )
```

To get that path, and launch the photo editor with:

```
Process.Start( <path to image> )
```

Thus, the photo app can write any changes back to that file.